# AlertDialog.Builder Activity leak

Tags: android, android-activity, memory-leaks

When we create an AlertDialog.Builder, we pass a context of the Activity who will show the Dialog.

```
      AlertDialog.Builder builder = new Builder(getActivity()); <<< Activity Context passed as argument
      mAlertDialog = builder.create();
      mAlertDialog.show();
```

Now to avoid ActivityLeakedException, we must dismiss() the dialog when Activity is destroyed. (Let us say on screen roatation).
This dismiss() would be called on Dialog reference and not on the builder. Even though we have called dismiss() on the Dialog, the builder is not made aware anyhow that Activity is getting destroyed  and it should release the context so builder is holding a reference to the Activity Context. Is this not leaking the Activity?

Comment: use (!getActivity().isFinishing()) mAlertDialog.show(); and try

Comment: I think once builder.create() is called, it will return you a alertdialog, and the builder object will be marked for gc.

Answer (score 1):

Although this may not fully answer your question, here are some observations:

As long as *builder* "is alive" the garbage collector may not touch the `Activity`.

Now code like the snippet in your question is typically part of some method which will be executed on the UI thread (because a UI element - the `AlertDialog` - is involved).

The `AlertDialog.Builder` instance is created inside of that method and so will be eligible for garbage collection as soon as the method is finished because then nothing will be holding a reference to it.

The Activity on the other hand will be around at least until `onPause()` has been called and returned.

> Is this not leaking the Activity?

Not as long as the method is running on the UI Thread. In other cases (e.g. `AsyncTask`), it may be a good idea to use a `WeakReference`. Or to use the application context where possible (for example with `SQLiteOpenHelper`).

By the way, recently I had an `AlertDialog` which vanished on orientation changes without my dismissing it (AS emulator, Lollipop). Logcat showed a message by `WindowManager` which mentioned my `Dialog` as "leaked window", so I think now that dismissing the `AlertDialog` is important to avoid memory leaks.

As I wanted to keep the dialog (and the user input so far) around, I switched to an `AlertDialog`-as-`DialogFragment` solution like the [sample](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomLayout) from documentation. Since then, the warning message has not been showing up.

Comment: If we try to use ApplicationContext for Dialog, it will crash. It needs reference to the Activity Context only.

Comment: @Sumit Trehan - yes, you are right about that. I mentioned the application context "where possible" because I thought of database helpers. But your dialog builder specifically seems to be no problem if it is created in a "normal" method on the UI Thread. Because it will be garbage collected as soon as the method finishes.

Comment: Because there will be no reference left *pointing to* this object. The problem with memory leaks is rather that somewhere some thread with a reference to my Activity could keep on running forever because I did not cancel it when the Activity went down.